# Repository Pattern where method takes too much RAM and loads unnecessary data

Tags: c#, repository

I have an image class.

```
public int Id{get; set;}
    public string ImageName{get; set;}
    public string CreatedDate{get; set;}
    public string ModifiedDate{get; set;}
    public string Url{get; set;}
 ......... Many more properties 
}
```

I have 100,000 Images in db. When i use repository Pattern to get images it takes to much memory.

`imageRepostery.GetAll().Where(x=> x.Id   == 1).ToList();`

This line gets all images from database, creates objects, and stores to RAM, then apply where condition and give me 1 image out of 100,000, then again destroy other object 99,999 objects.

How can i use where condition with repository Pattern without getting all data from database.

Edit:
And i want to use where condition Like this.
`List<MyImage> images = imageRepostery.GetAll().Where(x=> x.Id   > 500 || x.Id < 1000 ).ToList();`

Comment: So, why are you doing it that way? I don't think anything in the repository pattern tells you to fetch all images from the database into memory, and then filter them there.

Comment: We can't really give you a concrete recommendation (other than _"well don't do that"_) without seeing the repository code to understand what technologies it specifically uses so we can direct you to the appropriate methods to use to filter the records at the database, rather than in memory on your server.

Comment: If you have any solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Without implementation of your repository class, it will be all guesses..

Probably your generic implementation of `IRepository.GetAll()` returns `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` and basically you are retrieving all your entries every time.

If you like to have single result by Id better refactor your repository and have method like `T GetById(int Id)` and in its implementation return `.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Id == Id)`

Comment: Thanks for replying me. But i think you couldn't understand my problem. My repository obviously have GetById(int) method but main problem occur when i have to use where condition on other columns or apply multiple conditions like this.          List<MyImage> images = imageRepostery.GetAll().Where(x=> x.Id   > 500 || x.Id < 1000 ).ToList();

Comment: Stop using `.GetAll()` then. Either write a method which lets you filter the range of IDs (`GetIMagesWithIdInRange` or something), or give your repository a method which returns an `IQueryable<T>` which you can filter

Comment: @HamzaJaved Please post your Repository implementation and more specifically GetAll() implementation. If you use .ToList() in GetAll() method this will "flatten" your query and pull all your entries.